# Iterators can't be reused by another vector of the same size?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
vector< vector<int> >::iterator row;
vector<int>::iterator col;
vector<int>::iterator col2;



for (row = vec.begin(); row != vec.end(); row++) {

    col2 = row->begin(); //this needs to be row2 and row2 must be assigned with vec2.begin();

    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
    vec[col] = 23; //doesn't work because col is a pointer
    *col = 23;
    *col2 = 23; //overrides value pointed by *col


    col2++; 
    }
```

}

I was confused because when I print the iterator I get index values, so I am assuming that the << operator was overloaded to give you index values instead of the addresses the iterators are pointing to.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Could you give a concrete piece of code that compiles and gives output, and then compare that to what you expected?

Comment: What is `vec`? I am assuming it is a vector of integers?

Comment: `col` and `col2` are both initialised to `row->begin()` so why is it surprising they point to the same thing?

Comment: i was just wondering if iterators could be reused for 2 different containers, but I think it can't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, you cannot *safely* reuse an iterator from one instance of a container in another.  This is even more clear if you think of an iterator as a pointer.

```
int* pI = &some_int;
```

If I dereference `pI`, I expect to get the value of `some_int`.  It cannot, simultaneously, also point to `some_other_int`.

Without some specific useful code, I cannot propose an alternative solution.  However, since `std::vector` supports random access, if you wanted to access 2 elements of different vectors of the same size, you can just use an index instead:

```
std::vector<int> vec1(100, 1); // 100 elements initialized to 1
std::vector<int> vec2(100, 2); // 100 elements initialized to 2
std::vector<int> vec3(100);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size(); ++i) // we already know vec1, vec2, and vec3 are all the same size
{
    vec3[i] = vec1[i] + vec2[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
vector< vector<int> >::iterator row;
vector<int>::iterator col;
vector<int>::iterator col2;
for (row = vec.begin(); row != vec.end(); row++) {
    col2 = row->begin();
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        vec[col - row->begin()] = 23;
        *col = 23;
        *col2 = 23;
        col2++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
row2 = vec2->begin();
for (row = vec.begin(); row != vec.end(); row++)
{
    // ...
    row2++; 
}
```

Is it just the syntax that's bothering you? The fact that one iterator is handled inside the loop header, and the other one somewhere else? Because it is possible to handle both iterators inside the loop header:

```
for (row = vec.begin(), row2 = vec2->begin(); row != vec.end(); row++, row2++)
{
    // ...
}
```